# Divide Selection by X in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This will probably be a softball but how can I divide the selection by a certain amount?  In this case: 2.204623 ?  I know you can use "PasteSpecial" but I'm trying to figure out how to just have a selection and then assign a hotkey to do it (macro).

```
Sub Makemt()
 Dim Cell As Range
 Dim div_mt As Long

 div_kg = 2.204623

 For Each Cell In Selection
 Selection `here I would divide by div_mt

 Next

End Sub
```

I could not figure out how to blend the ability to pasteSpecial divide in which a selected range.

```
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: The `2.204623` would need to be in a cell to use the paste special.

Comment: is it not simply cell = cell/2.204623

Comment: Would it work if I have a named range where the 2.204623 is ?
So "selection" / named range ?

Comment: as long as the number is in a cell yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the loop and the number in a cell with:

```
Sub Makemt()    
 Dim div_mt As Double    
 div_mt = 2.204623

 Selection.Value = Selection.Parent.Evaluate("INDEX(" & Selection.Address & "/" & div_mt & ",)")

End Sub
```

If your value is in a cell then use this:

```
Sub Makemt()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K11").Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

K11 on Sheet1 would be the cell in which the value is found.

Comment: I don't know if there's a thing you can't answer Scott! Thank you!  The first part works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If each cell in range is to be divided

```
Sub Makemt()
 Dim Cell As Range
 Dim div_mt As Double

 div_kg = 2.204623

 For Each Cell In Selection

    If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then
        Cell = Cell/ div_kg
    End If

 Next Cell

End Sub
```

Edit: Taking note of @ScottCraner's note on numeric value in cell